# Почему xlsx файл пустой?

Tags: python, многопоточность, парсер, multiprocessing, openpyxl

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
start_time = time.time()
wb = Workbook()
wb.remove(wb.active)
ws = wb.create_sheet('Родирование')
ws.append(['Артикул', 'Родировине'])

cookies = {
'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'i1gip0fre5uzl4iqlkubv1cp',
'SLG_G_WPT_TO': 'ru',
'SLG_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp': '1',
'SLG_wptGlobTipTmp': '1',
'ICusrcartgd': 'be6d8ad2-c52e-49b8-83b2-f384a9feaa60',
'IWusrsesckgd': 'jojhbQMjYWEdV9ohRKijJKalgxKEvPEPzVqoH/F2376n50ziaNRcMA==',
}

headers = {
'authority': 'catalog.aquamarine.kz',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Opera GX";v="85"',
'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36 OPR/85.0.4341.79',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'origin': 'https://catalog.aquamarine.kz',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'referer': 'https://catalog.aquamarine.kz/catalog/index.aspx',
'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
# Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
# 'cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=i1gip0fre5uzl4iqlkubv1cp; SLG_G_WPT_TO=ru; SLG_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp=1; SLG_wptGlobTipTmp=1; ICusrcartgd=be6d8ad2-c52e-49b8-83b2-f384a9feaa60; IWusrsesckgd=jojhbQMjYWEdV9ohRKijJKalgxKEvPEPzVqoH/F2376n50ziaNRcMA==',
}


data = {
'msearch': '',
}
page = 0
page1=1


def get_page(cookies, headers, data,page): # Запросы к страницам
    return requests.post(page, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)

def getUrls():
    return [f'https://catalog.aquamarine.kz/catalog/products.ashx?rnd=8817290&q=&spec=&mip=317&map=7777%20777&mippg=161&mappg=5466%20222&miw=0.14&maw=137.74&miq=1&maq=241&miprcs=999999.999&maprcs=0&page={page}&sort=art-down&view=2&spc=1,&avid=5,&brid=7' for page in range(1, 3)]


def get_data(url,headers,cookies,data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_page(cookies, headers, data,url).text.replace('\\', ' '), 'lxml')
    contain = soup.find('div', class_='products')
    products = contain.find_all('div', class_='item wide')
    for product in products:
        link = 'https://catalog.aquamarine.kz'+(product.find('a').get('href'))
        req = requests.get(link, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
        articul = soup.find('td', text = 'Артикул').find_next_sibling('td').text
        data_rodirov = []
        try:
            rodirovs = soup.find_all('div', class_='center ssize')
            count = len(rodirovs)%5

            for i in range(1, int(count)+1):
                rodirov = soup.find_all('div', class_='center ssize')[i-1]
                size1 = rodirov.find_all('span')[0].text.strip()
                size2 = rodirov.find_all('span')[1].text.strip()
                size = size1 + size2
                data_rodirov.append(size)
            data_rodirov = ', '.join(data_rodirov)
            ws.append([articul, data_rodirov])
        except:
            raise
    

def main():

    p = Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    urls = getUrls()
    records = [(url, headers, cookies,data) for url in urls]
    p.starmap(get_data, records)
    wb.save('Родирование.xlsx')
    print(time.time()-start_time)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Почему когда код отрабатывает, я открываю файл, а там пусто? Может это как-то с мультипроцессингом связано. Когда я его убираю то всё работает

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Результат из get_data сохраняется во внешней переменной ws

ws.append([articul, data_rodirov])

Это не работает. Полученные результаты нужно записывать с помощью pipe или Queue. В главной программе нужно изменять ws, а потом его сохранять.

Comment: А всмысле главной программе нужно изменять ws

Comment: ws заполняется в отдельном процессе и не меняется в main

   wb.save('Родирование.xlsx')

Поэтому и записывается пустым. А за минус - спасибо. Больше пояснять не буду

Comment: Это не я поставил минус у меня даже рейтинга не хватает чтобы что-то ставить

Comment: Может быть кто-то случайно зашёл и нажал

Comment: Я же написал - полученные результаты можно получать, например, через механизм pipe. В документации есть примеры как это делать